# Need help reducing CSS line-height where type is skewed + underlined with border-bottom

Tags: html, css, skew

I'm attempting to reduce line-height on a headline that is skewed and underlined using border-bottom. However, adjusting the line-height causes the underline to move close to or behind my type.

```
.skewed {
display: inline-block;
font: 3em/1 poppins, sans-serif;
border-bottom: 7px solid white;
font-weight:600;
letter-spacing: 2px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
color: white;
margin-top: 1em;
position: relative;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
     -o-transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
        transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
           text-transform: uppercase;}
```

And here's my type:

```
<h1 class="skewed"><span>Nobody</span></h1>
<br>
<h1 class="skewed"><span>Ever Says</span></h1>
```

Here's an example. Any ideas how to tighten up the line height while retaining the thick text underline?

[Image example of headline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Gkq.jpg)

Comment: Does changing `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` instead solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use margins instead!

```css
body{
  background-color:#aaa;
}
.skewed{
  text-align:center;
}
.skewed span{
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:48px;
  font-family:helvetica;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#fff;
  border-bottom:7px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  margin-top:24px;
  transform: rotate(-15deg) skew(-15deg, 0);
}
```

```html
    <h1 class="skewed"><span>Nobody</span><br/><span>ever says</span><br/><span>seize</span><br/><span>tomorrow.</span></h1>
```